# 502 ошибка при обращении к внешнему JSON

Tags: python, json, django, веб-программирование

Пытаюсь разобрать json, скаченный по ссылке через Django. На вот этой строчке у меня стабильно загружается страница с 502 ошибкой и скрипт прекращается.

```py
json_data = requests.get(assortment_url).json().get('tires')
```

С локального компьютера тот же самый код работает нормально. То есть дело не в ошибках кода, а видимо в настройках сервера.

Вообще скрипт работает несколько минут. В чем может быть дело и какие настройки дергать?

Сообщение в логе ошибок nginx:
**upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream**

Содержимое uwsgi-конфига:

```
#my_app_uwsgi.ini 
[uwsgi]

# Настройки, связанные с Django
# Корневая папка проекта (полный путь)
chdir           = /home/kkomissarov/my_app/project

# Django wsgi файл
module          = my_app.wsgi

# полный путь к виртуальному окружению
home            = /home/kkomissarov/my_app/venv

# общие настройки
# master
master          = true
# максимальное количество процессов
processes       = 10
# полный путь к файлу сокета
socket          = /home/kkomissarov/my_app/project/my_app.sock
# права доступа к файлу сокета
# chmod-socket    = 664
# очищать окружение от служебных файлов uwsgi по завершению
vacuum          = true

#Рестарт при обновлении файла
touch-reload    = /home/kkomissarov/my_app/logs/reload.log

max-worker-lifetime = 900
```

Содержимое nginx-конфига:

```
upstream my_app {
    server unix:///home/kkomissarov/my_app/project/my_app.sock;
}

# конфигурация веб-сервера
server {
    # порт, который будет слушать веб-сервер в ожидании запросов от пользователй
    listen      80;
    # доменное имя
    server_name     my_app.ru; # замените на собственный домен или IP адрес
    charset     utf-8;

    # максимальный размер загружаемых на сервер данных
    client_max_body_size 75M;

    # обслуживание медиа файлов и статики
    location /media  {
       alias /home/kkomissarov/my_app/project/media;  # расположение медиафайлов (при необходимости измените)
    }

    location /static {
       alias /home/kkomissarov/my_app/project/static;  # расположение статики (при необходимости измените)
    }



    # Остальные запросы перенаправляются в Django приложение
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  my_app;
        include     /home/kkomissarov/my_app/deployment/uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_read_timeout 900s;
        proxy_connect_timeout      900;
        proxy_send_timeout         900;
        proxy_read_timeout         900;

}

    client_body_timeout 900s;
}
```

Comment: видимо надо смотреть почему 502 ошибка. читайте логи. прикрепите логи.

Comment: @ZaArs В лог запивыает вот что: **upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream**

Comment: Try increasing max-worker-lifetime. 35 seconds is very low. Источник: https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/1804 . У вас nginx + uwsgi ?

Comment: @ZaArs да, конфигурация такая. Я добавил содержимое конфига в вопрос. Добавил max-worker-lifetime, не помогло.

Comment: как формируется assortment_url ?

Comment: @ZaArs в эту переменную просто записана ссылка, в ней точно нет ошибки, т.к. этот же код нормально исполняется на локальном компьютере. Я обратил внимание, что такая же ошибка возникает вообще на любых долгих запросах, даже если они не тыкаются во внешние источники через requests.

Comment: ну киньте эту ссылку. проверим. или можете посмотреть в сторону увеличения времени выполнения скприпты, в uwsgi доке надо посмотреть

Comment: @ZaArs проблема, видимо, была в том, что настройки из конфига не применялись :) Хотя я перезагружал nginx. Перезапустил сервер целиком и вроде заработало.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, assortment_url не доступен с сервера (может быть, он содержит ссылку на localhost или недоступный номер порта)

Comment: нет, это исключено